# Trouble displaying RTMP stream on webpage. (Linux Ubuntu, Nginx)

Tags: server, vlc, nginx, streaming

I have setup an RTMP server on Linux Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using Nginx. I am able to stream successfully from OBS to the RTMP server and I am able to view the stream via VLC Media Player on a completely separate network so I know the stream works correctly.

What I am trying to do now is display the stream on my web servers index.html page but am having difficulty doing so.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but have got a little further than you !
I am using `ffmpeg` to decode the `rtmp` to `.m3u8` playlist where it stores the files in .ts parts .

```
install ffmpeg 
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

To decode from `rtmp`, you must switch on hls by editing your `nginx.conf` like this :

```
application live {
            live on;
            # Turn on HLS
            hls on;
            hls_path /stream/hls/;
            hls_fragment 3;
            hls_playlist_length 60;
            # disable consuming the stream from nginx as rtmp
            #deny play all;
```

( make sure you have made a directory /stream/hls ) to store the decrypted files in the directory

The code to decrypt the rtmp to that directory is

```
ffmpeg -v verbose -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/YOUR OBS STREAMKEY HERE -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -ac 1 -strict -2 -crf 18 -profile:v baseline -maxrate 400k -bufsize 1835k -pix_fmt yuv420p -flags -global_header -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 10 -start_number 1 /stream/hls/YOUROBSSTREAMKEY / or outputfilenamehere.m3u8
```

Paste above to putty and click. You will see the stream decoding/encoding in the directory folder if obs is running.

I have got this far ! I see the `m3u8` decoding but I am stuck on how to add the `m3u8` playlist to the webpage to play the stream live !

If anyone could update that would be great !

edit: I cannot view the `m3u8` in vlc aswell